# Excel use SUMIF but with a multiplier before summation: x2, x3, x4, etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that is using the SUMIF function. It works very well to summarize single values from another column but I want to be able to potentially multiply a single entries value before summing it.

I'm unable to attach photos so I'll try to describe. My spreadsheet has this equation on it:

```
=SUMIF(L25:L31,"x",$K$25:$K$31)
```

Then if I put an 'x' on a row in column 'L' it will include the value from column 'K' in the summation. I want to be able to use 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', etc. and multiply the value before the summation. Is that possible with Excel?

Comment: Why can't you just multiply the total, assuming you are applying the same operation to all matching cells?

Comment: You could also consider SUMPRODUCT, if you just used a number (1,2,3,4) instead of x1, x2, x3, x4. Your formula would just be =SUMPRODUCT(L25:L31,K25:K31). Any blank values are treated as zero. If you really want to have an x in front, you could do it with a custom cell format, rather than faffing around trying to strip out numeric values from a string.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGeatch, that works. I also figured out that I could do something like this using array calculations: `=SUM(SUMIFS($K$25:$K$31,L25:L31,{"x","x2","x3","x4"})*{1,2,3,4})`

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is distributive; the product of the sum is the same as the sum of the products. So you can move the multiplier to the outside of the equation if I am understanding your question correctly. Where "y" is the multiplier and "x" is the criteria you are looking up, the below should work:

`=y*SUMIF(L25:L31,"x",$K$25:$K$31)`

If the multiple is a variable, then I would suggest adding helper columns, and simply change the sum range on the `SUMIF` formula.

Note that the `SUMPRODUCT` suggested does not take into account the conditional nature of the sum that I assume you are looking for (otherwise why would you use `SUMIF` instead of `SUM`?)

Comment: That won't work as there are only single pieces that I want to multiply, not the whole sum. Like one row may be just 'x' so add that in once, another row may have x4 so add that row 4 times (or multiply by 4). Like this:
`row1  $50 x`
`row2 $20 x2`
`row3 $10 x3`

That should sum up to $120

Comment: Got it, so the multiplier is a variable. I'm assuming you do not want to alter the original data, so would then suggest adding and then hiding helper columns. Let Column M be the multiple of the row you want, then let Column N be =M*row value. You can then use =SUMIF(L25:L31, "x", $N$25:$N$31)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR($K$25:$K$31*IF($L$25:$L$31="x",1,MID($L$25:$L$31,2,255)),0))
```

But must the "x" be there? If you have the flexibility to switch to 1, 2, 3 instead of x, x2 and x3, that would open up to simplify the formula to this

```
=SUMPRODUCT($K$25:$K$31*$L$25:$L$31)
```

The latter should be more efficient as well, in case your actual data is large.

Answer (score 0):

If I've not misunderstood, this would produce the result of applying a variable multiplier to the qualified data points and then sum it up:

```
=SUM( (L25:L30="x") * K25:K30 * {1;2;3;4;5;6} )
```

The 1;2;3... column array is arbitrary - I just invented it for example.  If it really is an incremental sequence, then you can produce the same this way and gain the advantage that it is easier to extend (without typing lots of numbers):

```
=SUM( (L25:L30="x") * K25:K30 * SEQUENCE( ROWS(L25:L30) ) )
```

If this is the solution and you really want to streamline it, then make it a little cleaner with LET:

```
=LET( sumRange, K25:K30,
      criteriaRange, L25:L30,
      criteria, "x",
       size, MIN( ROWS( criteriaRange), ROWS( sumRange ) ),
       SUM( (criteriaRange = criteria ) * sumRange * SEQUENCE( size ) ) )
```

If the multipliers are not an incremental sequence, then a third variable could be introduced to replace SEQUENCE( size ) that would contain the multiplier array.